# PropertyAccessor Outlook

Tags: properties, outlook

```c#
PropertyAccessor opa = outlookitem.PropertyAccessor;
opa.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{FFF40745-D92F-4C11-9E14-92701F001EB3}/Id", "100");
var val = opa.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{FFF40745-D92F-4C11-9E14-92701F001EB3}/Id");
```

When i try this on my own calendar (outlookitem) created in my calendar it works fine. But when i add a colleagues calendar to my Outlook at try it there i get the following exception, when calling GetProperty.

Any ideas?

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in *** but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{FFF40745-D92F-4C11-9E14-92701F001EB3}/Id" is unknown or cannot be found.
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? Do you actually set and read back the property immediately? Or is there an interval between the calls?

Comment: There is an interval between, which gives the same error. This is just for testing

Comment: Is it possible that the appointment is recreated before the second code snippet runs? This can happen if Outlook receives a meeting update.

Comment: Dont think so. But thanks for the suggestion. It gets more weird. It seems that if i set the permission level to Free/Busy time, subject, location im able to read it. The permission i had was Publishing Editor

Comment: I had to save the item before a accessing the property. Not it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to save the item before a accessing the property. Not it works. Thanks